# How do I dynamically load a smaller texture in Unity based on the screen size?

Tags: unity, textures, texture-atlas

I have a Unity application on windows phone which is having problems running on small devices because the HD textures are so huge. What is the best way to test and dynamically use a smaller version on a smaller or less powerful device?

Comment: You could check which device it is and load the appropriate image/s using Resources.Load()

Comment: You are talking about different sized WindowsPhones, are you? Because you could override the texture size for the whole platform to something smaller very easily (texture import settings).

Comment: We are talking about low end and high end phones on the same platform (windows phone).